# When used as a monitor on Duet Display, is the iPad software accessible?

Tags: macbook-pro, ipad, dual-screen

A non-techie friend got [Duet Display](https://www.duetdisplay.com/). She wants to use it to attach her iPad to her MacBook (Pro?) in order to have two screens.

However, she also wants to be able to access something on the iPad (a site for which she only has access from her iPad) and then copy and paste over to a document on the Mac side.

From the little I know about Duet, it appears that, while the iPad is being used as a second monitor, it is *not* simultaneously usable as an iPad. Is that correct?

Can she use the iPad's functionality while Duet is using the iPad as a second monitor for the Mac?

Comment: Thanks Giacomo.